# Maintaining vozac_id (driver_id) in ev_gor_km (fuel_kilometer_log) Table After Deleting Corresponding Record in vozaci (drivers)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a PHP web application involving two MySQL tables: `vozaci` (drivers) and `ev_gor_km` (evident of fuel and km). In both tables, there's a column named `vozac_id`. In `ev_gor_km`, `vozac_id` is a foreign key referencing `vozac_id` in `vozaci`.

The application includes functionality for managing drivers (stored in `vozaci`) and recording fuel/km data (in `ev_gor_km`), where a driver's ID is selected. I've set up the following foreign key constraints:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `ev_gor_km`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ev_gor_km_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vozac_id`) REFERENCES `vozaci` (`vozac_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ev_gor_km_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`cc_id`) REFERENCES `cost_center` (`cc_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ev_gor_km_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`car_id`);
COMMIT;
```

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to delete a driver from `vozaci`. The deletion triggers an error due to the foreign key constraint with `ev_gor_km`. I understand that using `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL` would resolve this error, but neither of these actions align with my requirement.

**My specific challenge**: I want to keep the `vozac_id` value in `ev_gor_km` unchanged even after the corresponding `vozac_id` is deleted from `vozaci`. Is there a way to achieve this while maintaining data integrity and without breaking the foreign key constraint? How can I handle the deletion such that it doesn't affect the linked records in `ev_gor_km`?

Here's my PHP deletion code, if relevant:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/db.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM vozaci WHERE vozac_id = (:id)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  header("Location: ../stranica/korisnik.php");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p style="color: red;">Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Any guidance or alternative approaches for handling this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove the foreign key, it is the think that will check if the value exists in the other tab,le

Comment: @nbk Idk why, but why do I think that you're trying to troll me? lol 
If I delete foreign key then I can't have reference? Which furthermore means troubles for me -> `vozac_id` from table `ev_gor_km` won't be "linked" to the `vozaci` table

Comment: foreign keys are only a check constraint for tables with additional code for update and delete, so you can always build a trigger to have the check simulated and of course the update and delete as well. You asked how to keep the valuet and i answered the best way i could

Comment: @nbk Well, technically yes - you did provided answer because I didn't specify that my goal is also to still have references.  I know that this isn't right, but as this is still related to this question, `UPDATE ev_gor_km SET vozac_id=OLD.vozac_id WHERE vozac_id=OLD.vozac_id;` would be something that I am looking for when it comes to trigger?

Comment: i think you want the new updated vozac_id and not the old o0ne, when it is updated.

Comment: Using non-English, project-specific terms in your question title will not help future readers to understand what this page is discussing.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for pointing it out, I edited title and made it clear in a way that I added translation inside of `( )`, also within the question I am using non-english words, but I am explaining what's meaning of them, so hopefully this way the question itself is improved so somebody in future might benefit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what I did is archive instead of deletion, which means that instead of directly deleting the driver's record from the `vozaci` table, new column was added and named `is_active`, therefore it indicated whether a driver is currently active or not, and when  I need to remove a driver, I simply setted this flag to `false`, instead of deleting record itself, which helped me to retain the `vozac_id` in the `vozaci` table, therefore I ensured that the foreign key reference in the `ev_gor_km` table remains intact.

Since I did this, I had to update the application logic in a way that this logic is treating drivers with `is_active` set to false as if they were deleted, that being said, they are not displayed in the driver management section ro available for selection in the `fuel/km` recording section, also I had to adjust database query, i.e. when fetching the list of driver for selection in the ev_gor_km section I added a `WHERE is_active = true` clause. Also for historical data in `ev_gor_km` that references drivers no longer active, I had to ensure that the application can handle these references so to say, gracefully, in a way that I displayed placeholder "Driver Not Available" in the user interface.
Basically, what I did is "soft delete" in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/db.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE vozaci SET is_active = false WHERE vozac_id = (:id)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  header("Location: ../stranica/korisnik.php");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p style="color: red;">Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Generally, `$_GET` requests should not lead to a "writing" action on the server.  `POST` is for writing data (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), and `GET` is for reading data (SELECT).

Comment: @mickmackusa As it's an old project of mine, in this specific case, I used `GET` for simplicity in the example code, but in a production environment, it's indeed better to use `POST` for such operations to ensure data integrity and security which is also an important aspect of web application development, and I appreciate your emphasis on adhering to these standards for the benefit of anyone reading this thread.